# How to do string concatenation with Javascript in Laravel view?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have **`data.data[key].thumb`** and **`data.data[key].image`** as variables and this is inside `<script>` tag in a Laravel Blade template.

There is an error in this line, causing this:

> Use of undefined constant uploads - assumed 'uploads'

The code is:

```
user_status += '<img src="{{asset(uploads/' + data[key].image + '.' + 
                data[key].thumb + ')}}" class="img-responsive" 
                style="height:290px;" alt="360-video-feature" /></div>';

user_status += '<img class="OverlayIcon" src=" 
                {{asset('uploads/video_icon_overlay.png')}}" alt="" />';
```

Comment: i feel like you user_status should be like this: `user_status += '<img class="OverlayIcon" src=" 
                {{asset(\'uploads/video_icon_overlay.png\')}}" alt="" />';` 
As it is now i'am unsure if the simple quotes in the middle are really understood as part of the string and not just as both stop and start markers.

Comment: I dont think second one is problem because if i remove first one the error is gone

Comment: I don't know then, just felt like this was weird

Comment: maybe you are missing the single quote before uploads? Should be `'uploads/' + data[key].image`

Comment: Quotes are just part of the problem. It seems you're mixing JS and PHP variables, and that's not possible to do the way you're doing. This: `{{ asset(uploads/' + data[key].image + '.' + data[key].thumb + ') }}` won't work even if you fix the quotes. That's because `data` var is only available after your Blade template is compiled and displayed on the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can not mix PHP and JavaScript like this. The PHP code is executed on the server when rendering the view, and JavaScript on the client side. Even if it was possible, your syntax would still be incorrect.

`user_status += '<img src="{{asset(uploads/' + data[key].image` you are missing a quote before `uploads/`. It should be `"uploads`.

What you can do is:

```
user_status += '<img src="' +
               '{{asset("uploads/")}}' + data[key].image + '.' + data[key].thumb + '"' +
               ' class="img-responsive" style="height:290px;" alt="360-video-feature" /></div>';
```

This way, `'{{asset("uploads/")}}'` will be replaced with the URL string to the uploads folder, and the rest of the URL will appended via JavaScript. This is how the browser will see it:

```
user_status += '<img src="' +
               'http://www.example.com/uploads/' + data[key].image + '.' + data[key].thumb + '"' +
               ' class="img-responsive" style="height:290px;" alt="360-video-feature" /></div>';
```